# jQuery EACH siblings to EACH variable?

Tags: jquery

I ahve a jquery code that get the siblings of a table td text.
How can we put that text into variables?

```
jQuery("tbody tr").each(function() {
    jQuery("td:not(:first)",this).click(function() {
        alert(jQuery(this).siblings().text());
    });
});

<table>
<thead><td>A</td><td>B</td></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="aclass">A</td><td class="bclass">B</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Set siblings as variable:

var txtA = jQuery(this).find(".aclass").text();
var txtA = jQuery(this).find(".aclass").text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the texts in array:

```
var textsArr = new Array();
jQuery("tbody tr").each(function() {
    jQuery("td:not(:first)",this).click(function() {
        textsArr.push(jQuery(this).siblings().text());
    });
});
```

Comment: when I alert the alert(textsArr);
It is still the same it just put it in array but only one array 
array("one array");
It should be array("one","array");